# Does LG 49UB850T model support webOS IDE v1.0.0 build ipk

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv

I have created a LG webos smart tv app. I have created .ipk file through webOS IDE v1.0.0 SDK.

Does LG 49UB850T smart TV model support this ipk file? If yes, then please confirm me, so that i can purchase that TV. It cost around Rs.1,44,000.

This is the TV link http://www.lg.com/in/tvs/lg-49UB850T

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your question in the [LG Developer Forum](http://developer.lge.com/community/forums/RetrieveForumList.dev?prodTypeCode=TV) so you can find out the requirements for testing apps on TVs. That is a webOS TV so, in theory, should be compatible with the SDK (BTW, SDK 2.0 is available).  However, you are required to have the developer mode app on the TV in order to test apps. This is what you need to clarify with the webOS TV developer program.